# Why can't I open this .pst from a network drive?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I have a pst file on a mapped network drive that I can't open.

> The file *path to file* cannot be opened.

If I copy the file to a local drive and ope it, it works just fine. I have other .pst files in the same remote directory that open fine - some of them are larger than the one I'm trying to open.

Why is this happening?

Comment: One thing you should know is that it's not recommended to store PSTs on a network drive (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A .pst file can only be opened by **one person at a time**.

If the .pst file is on a network drive, does someone else have it added to Outlook?